# Show that there are no onto homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_{18}$ to $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know that the kernel has to be $\{0, a, a^{-1}\}$, where "$a$" is in $\mathbb{Z}_{18}$, but I'm kind of stuck after that. It seems like the factor group $\mathbb{Z}_{18}/\{0, a, a^{-1}\}$ has $18$ elements, but I don't know how to prove that. Could someone help me with that part, or suggest another way of proving this if I'm going about this the wrong way? Thanks.

Comment: Your description of the possible kernel mixes additive notation ($0$) and multiplicative notation ($a^{-1}$). That's asking for confusion (unless it's the result of a pre-existing confusion).

Comment: @AndreasBlass I am sure it is the latter.

Comment: Yep, probably. I thought a^-1 was valid notation for an inverse in additive or multiplicative notation though. Should I have used a'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}_{18}$ is an abelian group, $S_3$ -- not so much.

Comment: may be too early for an answer :O +1 though :)

Comment: That's enough to prove there's no homomorphism? I could see why it would work the other way, as there are normal subgroups for S3 other than (), but I'm still a bit confused... And thanks for the super fast response!

Comment: @LMNOP the homomorphic image of an abelian group is always abelian.

Comment: Oh, wait, so if phi(a*b=c)=phi(a)*phi(b), that means phi(b*a=c) won't equal phi(b)*'phi(a) for all a, b in G, since that's the definition of a function not being abelian. (Poorly worded, but I get it now)

Comment: Right, thanks! Sorry for the dumb question

Comment: Functions aren’t abelian, groups are.

Comment: Right. I should have said that there is some phi(b)*'phi(a) that does not equal phi(a)*'phi(b) because the **group** S3 is not abelian.

Comment: @LMNOP, it is not true that «it does not equal»: it depends on what a and b are!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I said there is _some_ phi(b)*'phi(a), meaning some a and b, which does not equal phi(a)*'phi(b).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\phi :\mathbb Z_{18} \to S_3$ is surjective. Then $\mathbb Z_{18} / Ker(\phi) \cong S_3$ by the first isomorphism theorem. However the thing on the left is abelian but the thing on the right is not. This is more or less the same as Igor's answer.

Comment: it has been already said by above answer right? :O

Comment: Right, which is why I said it was more or less the same as Igor's answer, but they're certainly not identical.

Answer (score 1):

The group $Z_{18}$ is cyclic, so that so is its image under an homomorphism. But the group $S_3$ is not cyclic: indeed, its order is $6$ and its elements have order $1$, $2$ or $3$.